# Selecting a field from a drop box to download an excel file using java

Tags: java, html, excel, junit, download

I need to download a file from the following URL.

> http://www.census.gov/manufacturing/m3/
>
> (Advance report highlights->excel selection menu ->Table 1)

as soon as we click a selection from the drop box, the web browser directly prompts to download and save the excel file.

Can you suggest a method to go about this ?
I am attempting this using `HtmlUnit` with the following code.

I get a Null pointer at line `HtmlOption option = select.getOption(2);`

If there is a better solution with another class, I would not mind considering that as well.

```
public static void startDownload() throws Exception {

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.census.gov/manufacturing/m3/");

    HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("advance_xls");
    HtmlOption option = select.getOption(2);
  
    webClient.closeAllWindows();/**/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the code,there was some minor mistake :

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.census.gov/manufacturing/m3/");

HtmlSelect select = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementByName("advanced_xls");

InputStream is =  select.setSelectedAttribute("/manufacturing/m3/adv/table2a.xls",true).getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
```

The excel sheet will be downloaded as inputStream then you need to create excel sheet from it.

Comment: It worked.
Is there an alternate method to do this ?

Comment: What do u mean by alternative method ??

Comment: using some other class or package completely different from the above ? Asking just out of curiosity

Comment: If u r talking abt different way in HtmlUnit then instead of HtmlSelect we can use HtmlElement to get the element but later we need to cast to HtmlSelect.Other can this i dnt thnk any way exist